# error: not well-formed (invalid token). Comparison signs in TextView text attribute

Tags: android, android-layout

I have complicated layout for android fragment. I will show only two TextView's, situation doesn't depends of another components.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bet_min"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="> 10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bet_max"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="< 20"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/bet_min"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The StackTrace output of :
Output:  C:\someUser\user\dc\pr\a\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_some.xml:19: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

I expected that problem is in second View, attribute:
android:text="< 25000"
Without this attribute everything is Ok.

Question is: Why AS reacts like this on '>' attribute, especially if in first View I have attribute '<'?

Comment: `... Why AS reacts like this ...` It's not AS. Also Eclipse does. It's the XML parser, which recognizes the **<** and **>** as XML tag delimiters.

Comment: Sorry, XML-Parser. Funny is that it parse '<' attribute, but not '>'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use  the **`<`** and **`>`** sign directly In XML

- To use **<**  Use **`&lt;`**
- To use **>**  Use **`&gt;`**

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bet_min"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="&gt; 10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bet_max"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="&lt; 20"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/bet_min"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Question is: Why AS reacts like this on '>' attribute, especially if in first View I have attribute '<'?

Please read this [**`What are the special characters in XML?`**](http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply and article! It will be a good addition for me.